# null check in jsf expression language

Tags: java, jsf, el

Please see this Expression Language

```
styleClass="#{obj.validationErrorMap eq null ? ' ' :  
     obj.validationErrorMap.contains('key')?'highlight_field':'highlight_row'}"
```

Even if the map is null, `highlight_row` style is getting applied.

So I changed to

```
styleClass="#{empty obj.validationErrorMap ? ' ' :  
     obj.validationErrorMap.contains('key')?'highlight_field':'highlight_row'}"
```

Even then, `highlight_row` is getting applied.
if the map is `empty OR null` I dont want any style  to be applied.

Any help? and reasons for this behaviour?

Comment: are you using the JBoss EL extension?

Comment: I think Yes. jboss-el.jar is present in server\appl\lib Folder.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use `empty` (it checks both nullness and emptiness) and group the nested ternary expression by parentheses (EL is in certain implementations/versions namely somewhat problematic with nested ternary expressions). Thus, so:

```
styleClass="#{empty obj.validationErrorMap ? ' ' :  
 (obj.validationErrorMap.contains('key') ? 'highlight_field' : 'highlight_row')}"
```

If still in vain (I would then check JBoss EL configs), use the "normal" EL approach:

```
styleClass="#{empty obj.validationErrorMap ? ' ' :  
 (obj.validationErrorMap['key'] ne null ? 'highlight_field' : 'highlight_row')}"
```

**Update**: as per the comments, the `Map` turns out to actually be a `List` (please work on your naming conventions). To check if a `List` contains an item the "normal" EL way, use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`fn:contains`](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/contains.fn.html) (although not explicitly documented, it works for `List` as well).

```
styleClass="#{empty obj.validationErrorMap ? ' ' :  
 (fn:contains(obj.validationErrorMap, 'key') ? 'highlight_field' : 'highlight_row')}"
```